# Decals for LEGO Pharaoh's Quest Flying Mummy

Tags: stickers, replacement-parts

Do all LEGO sets have decals?  I am specifically looking for decals for LEGO Pharaoh's Quest Flying Mummy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any, but there are at least 67 of them available on Bricklink: http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=7307stk01

(and no, not all sets have stickers)